# Navegar entre fragmentos desde activity

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo una actividad la cual tiene un Navhostfragment y unos botones, los botones quiero usarlos para cambiar entre fragmentos.

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

Estoy usando navigation component, entonces para cambiar de fragmento he intentado lo siguiente

**ACTIVITY**

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)   

 
            btnone.setOnClickListener {
                Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_oneFragment)

            findNavController(R.id.fragment).navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_oneFragment)
            Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_oneFragment)

            val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
            val navController = navHostFragment.navController

            navController.navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_oneFragment)

            this.findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_oneFragment)

        }
```

Sin embargo ninguno de esto funciona, cualquiera de ello termina generando un error.
Vale decir que he usado antes navigation component, junto con un navigationbuttom y cambiaba desde un fragmento entre fragmentos con lo siguiente

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.navegar_home)
```

Tambien funciona en mi proyecto actual.

Pero ahora necesito hacerlo desde la activity, ya que los botones están ahí, en la documentación indica lo siguiente sin embargo también me genera error, espero estar implementándolo correctamente
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#navigate

**EDITADO**
Encontre esto en un CodeLab, aun sigo encontrando la solución

> Tu NavControllerestá asociado con un NavHostFragment. Por lo tanto,
> sea cual sea el método que utilice, debe asegurarse de que el
> fragmento, la vista o el ID de la vista sea en NavHostFragmentsí mismo
> o tenga NavHostFragmentcomo padre. De lo contrario, obtendrá un
> IllegalStateException.

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-navigation#4

**ERROR:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.testlab.toptag, PID: 17510
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination com.testlab.toptag:id/navegar_home cannot be found from the current destination Destination(com.testlab.toptag:id/homeFragment) label=fragment_home class=com.testlab.toptag.home.HomeFragment
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:940)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:877)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:863)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:851)
        at com.testlab.toptag.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:21)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7869)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14958)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7838)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:886)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29362)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8107)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

NavGraph

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.testlab.toptag.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/navegar_one"
            app:destination="@id/oneFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/oneFragment"
        android:name="com.testlab.toptag.One.OneFragment"
        android:label="fragment_one"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_one" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/navegar_home"
            app:destination="@id/homeFragment" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Deseo lograr esto
[image]

Comment: no crees que deberías mostrar el mensaje de error?

Comment: Acabo de agregarlo, gracias por el aviso.

Comment: muestra también el navGraph

Comment: Agregado, aun no logro entender que puede estar pasando según la documentación  al parecer si es posible realizar el cambio en una actividad..

Comment: claro que es posible pero se ve que no lo implementaste bien. Agrega tu activity completa

Comment: Ya edite, esa es toda mi actividad

Comment: Agregue una imagen de lo que deseo lograr, como ven es un comportamiento lineal, es decir ningún fragment tendrá hijos, todos estarán en el mismo nivel, entonces podría simplemente usar fragment transaction en lugar de usar el navigation component.
Que me sugieren ya que no logro solucionarlo, talvez alguien podría compartir un proyecto de ejemplo donde se pueda realizar el cambio desde la actividad.

Comment: te sugiero que hagas una nueva pregunta y por favor que esté bien formulada. Lo que hiciste ahora es mezclar todo el código que probaste de forma que no se puede reproducir. Por ejemplo estás llamando `navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_oneFragment)` pero en tu graph no tienes ninguna action con ese id. Por favor lee [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Ese error es fácíl de resolver si das la información correcta

Answer (score 0):

Creo que podrías cambiar lo que hay en tu setOnClickListener por algo como

```
btnone.setOnClickListener{
val action = HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToOneFragment( )
    findNavController().navigate(action)
}
```

Con eso debería ser suficiente para navegar entre fragments.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUCION**
Para navegar entre fragmentos desde un activity

```
button.setOnClickListener {
            Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.viewBalanceFragment)
        }
```

encontre un proyecto en el que no me dejaba usar findNavController simplemente tuve que usar `Navigation` al inicio

```
Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.viewBalanceFragment)
```

1. this --> referencia a la actividada
2. R.id.nav_host_fragment --> id de tu NavHostFragment
3. R.id.viewBalanceFragment  --> id del fragment
   agregado a tu grafico de navegación, **no confundir con la acción
   que lleva a el fragmet, ese fue mi error.**

**Explicacion**
Después de un largo tiempo, revisando el siguiente https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-navigation#0 Codelab, pude percatarme de mi error. Según lo que he entiendo, en todos mis intentos anteriores estaba pasando como destino de navegación una acción, sin embargo observando detenidamente el grafico de navegación, pude ver que existían dos acciones con el mismo id, entonces me pregunte como sabe el controlador adonde tiene que ir, así pude darme cuenta que es gracias el fragmento desde donde se esta cambiando, es decir si tengo dos acciones **next**, pero la estoy llamando de un fragment A, entonces se tomara como referencia ese fragment y se cambiara al fragment que este vinculado/conectado con ese fragment.

Entonces si se necesita saber desde donde se esta llamando, no se podría cambiar de fragmento por medio de las acciones **desde la actividad**, ya que la actividad no estaría conectada a ningún fragmento, y generaría el error que me genero, y bueno la única solución que se me ocurrió fue llamar directamente al fragmento usando la id que posee en el grafico de navegación, eso funciono.

El único inconveniente que note es que, si presiono muchas veces el botón para cambiar de fragmento, se crean varias instancias de el, entonces si quiero regresar con el botón de retroceso, tengo que pasar por todas esas instancias creadas para poder llegar al home, abriré una pregunta acerca de esto.
Gracias a todos los que apoyaron.

Comment: La conclusión es erronea, ocurre totalmente lo opuesto. El controller no sabe desde donde lo llamas ni tampoco le interesa. Él es el que hace las transacciones y por lo tanto siempre sabe cuál es el fragment actual. Navegar usando el id de los fragments en lugar de usar el de las actions no es una solución, es un workaround. El error real sigue existiendo y te causará problemas más adelante. Lo único que hiciste fue ocultarlo

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, la tomare en cuenta por si surgen problemas. 
En ese caso como podría  realizar lo que deseo, desde el proyecto de codelabs, ahí debe estar implementado todo correctamente, entonces como podría cambiar a un fragmento desde la actividad.
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-navigation#1

Comment: Te contesto si creas una nueva pregunta